# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure Paypal adaptive payment

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

The bellow is my curl config of PPHttpConfig.php for paypal adaptive payment SDK,

```
 public static $DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS = array(
                CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 4,
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,   // maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'PayPal-PHP-SDK',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(),
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
                CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1',
        );
```

But,getting error

> Type  PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException
>
> Message   error:14077410:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL error messages tend towards cryptic and generic.

The most common causes for this error are that

- the server certificate has expired
- the server cerificate is invalid
- the client and server can not negotiate a protocol level or cipher acceptable to both parties.

Your version of OpenSSL is relatively recent (but still out of date / [containing serious vulnerabilities](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.1-notes.html)). I'd like to think that PayPal wouldn't let their certificates expire.

Less common reasons for seeing this error are

- your database is CA certs is out of date
- CACert database can't be found (is your PHP running in a chroot?)
- you've got some silly entries in your openssl.cnf or it can't be found
- you are sitting behind a MITM proxy you didn't know about

You didn't say where the PHP is running, what its running on, nor what acces you have to the machine. If it's a Linux box and you have shell access, you might want to see what happens when you [probe the server](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers) from the command line.